# ELMAH MVC Route not displaying

Tags: elmah, elmah.mvc

I just installed ELMAH.Mvc and left all the default configurations and I am able to get to the elmah route and see my log. however, when i deploy my application I get a 403 Forbidden Access page. I thought since I had the requiresAuthentication flag set to false it would be available. Here are my settings:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
```

any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

doh! I needed to add this to my web.config:

```
<security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
```